# Rails Form Associations - Passing id From Previous Page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, model-associations

Trying to figure our how to set up associations in form.

I have 3 models:

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  has many :answers
  has many :users, through: :answers
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs to :user
   belongs to :request
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has many :answers
   has many :requests, through: :answers
end
```

I am trying to figure out: how to have a User link to `Answer#new` from `Request#Show`, and then create an Answer record passing in the `Request#Show` `request_id` from the previous page - creating an association between the User's `Answer` and the `Request` he was viewing.

My method of doing this now is: I flash the `request_id` value on `Request#Show`, and then when a User links to `Answer#new`, it passes the flashed value into a hidden form tag on Answer#new. This does not seem like the best way to do this.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kudos for the creative approach using flash, however your right there is an easy way. You can pass parameters much between controllers just like passing parameters between methods using the route names.

I didn't quite follow what it was you were trying to achieve in this case but it looks like this blog entry here should get you started..

https://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2013/08/31/how-to-pass-parameters-as-part-of-the-url-in-rails/

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

> User link to `Answer#new` from `Request#Show`

This can be achieved with either [`sessions`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sessions) or [`nested resources`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) (or both!). Let me explain:

---

I would definitely add a *nested resource* to your `requests` routes:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :requests do
   resources :answers, only: [:new, :create] #-> url.com/requests/:request_id/answers [POST]
end
```

This gives you the ability to call a "nested" route (IE one which sends data to a child controller, and requires "parent" data to be appended to the request).

In your case, you want to create an *answer* for a *request*. The most efficient way is to use a routing structure as above; this will allow you to use the following controller method:

```
#app/controllers/answers_controller.rb
class AnswersController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @request = Request.find params[:request_id]
      @answer = @request.answers.new
   end

   def create
      @request = Request.find params[:request_id]
      @answer = @request.answers.new answer_params
      @answer.save
   end

   private

   def answer_params
      params.require(:answer).permit(:title, :body)
   end
end
```

The above gives you the ability to *create* an answer by passing the `request_id` to the nested route. You must note the corresponding route will require a **POST** method in order to work.

You don't need the `new` method. If you wanted it, it can easily be handled with the above structure.

---

Passing the *user* is a little more tricky.

You can *either* use the routes, or set a *session*.

I would personally set a session (it's cleaner):

```
#app/controllers/requests_controller.rb
class RequestsController < ApplicationController
   def show
      session[:user_id] = @user.id #-> I don't know how you populate @user
   end
end
```

This will give you the ability to access this session here:

```
#app/controllers/answers_controller.rb
class AnswersController < ApplicationController
   def new
      user = User.find session[:user_id]
   end
end

#app/views/requests/show.html.erb
<%= link_to "New Answer", request_new_answer_path(request) %>
```

--

If you're using *Devise*, the user object should be available in the [`current_user` object](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers) (which means you don't have to set `session[:user_id]`):

```
#app/controllers/answers_controller.rb
class AnswersController < ApplicationController
   def new
      ## current_user available here if using devise
   end
end
```

To assign a `@user` to the new `answer` record, just do this in `answers#create`:

```
#app/controllers/answers_controller.rb
class AnswersController < ApplicationController
   ...

   def create
      @request     = Request.find params[:request_id]
      @answer      = @request.answers.new answer_params
      @answer.user = current_user
      @answer.save
   end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this worked for me:

- I have two models (Formula and FormulaMaterial)
- Formula has_many FormulaMaterials, which belongs to Formula
- My Formula controller sets @formula like so:

  @formula = Formula.find(params[:id])
- I list my Formula Materials in my Formula show.html.erb by declaring it in my Formula controller like so:

  @formula_materials = FormulaMaterial.where(:formula_id => @formula)
- When I want to add a new FormulaMaterial to my Formula, the "New Formula Material" button in my show.html.erb file looks like this:

  ```
  <%= link_to 'Add Material To Formula', new_formula_material_path(:formula_id => @formula), class: "btn btn-success" %>
  ```
- In the "new_..._path" I set the associated id to the @formula variable. When it passes through to the new.html.erb for my FormulaMaterial, my URL looks like so:

  http://localhost:3000/formula_materials/new?formula_id=2
- In my FormulaMaterial new.html.erb file, I created a hidden_field that sets the value of the association by using "params" to access the formula_id in the URL like so:

  params[:formula_id] %>

I am not sure if this is the best way to do this, but this way has allowed me to pass through the view id from the previous page as a hidden, associated and set field in the form every time.

Hope this helps!